# java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream happened when i uploaded a image to server by okhttp

Tags: java, android, image, upload, okhttp

The error happened when i upload a 115KB image file to server.(the most answer of stackoverflow is about download the file.I do not know if it is the same to those)
the error information is below:
onFailure : java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

Relevant Code:

```
public void upLoadImageFile(String uploadUrl, File file, Map<String, String> maps, final HWUploadListener listener) {


    final CallbackHandler handler = new CallbackHandler(listener);

    try {
        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        if (maps == null) {
            builder.addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\"file.jpg\""),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)).build();

        } else {
            for (String key : maps.keySet()) {
                builder.addFormDataPart(key, maps.get(key));
            }
            builder.addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\";filename=" + file.getName()), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
            );
        }


        RequestBody body = builder.build();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(uploadUrl).post(body).build();

        final Call call = mOkHttpClient.newBuilder().writeTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build().newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                UtilUtils1.log("HuowuSdk", "onFailure ：" + e.toString());
                handler.uploadFailure(e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String result = response.body().string();
                    handler.uploadSuccess(result);

                } else {
                    handler.uploadFailure(response.message());
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        UtilUtils1.log("HuowuSdk", e.toString());
        handler.uploadError(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Appreciate your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Here in this line below you have to increase write timeout because while uploading your write timeout expires that may be the reason so in below line increase writeTimeout limit:

```
final Call call = mOkHttpClient.newBuilder().writeTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build().newCall(request);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I have written timeout limit before that.The issue still happened.